# Remove UUID, Created, ID, etc fields from "HTML Table" Export

Tags: webforms

I want to know how can i remove the fields from the module "Scheduled Tasks" for Webform, so the exported Excel file doesn't show the fields "Created" "UUID" "Serial Number" "Completed" etc. I can make it when i export manually but in scheduled tasks it sends all that information. I don't have a clue how to make it.

[image: These are the items i want to remove form HTML Table]

Comment: It was the same problem I had, and at the time when I was using it in d7.
I don't think that possibility exists, or at least, when I looked for a solution myself I couldn't find anything that would allow it.
Maybe it would take a sub-module that would remove those parameters on export (I used to export them to Excel), but I couldn't find any mention of such a module and I'm not able to implement it. I gave up for the moment, and I used to delete columns I'm not interested in from the files. Hopefully, in Drupal 9, someone will implement this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Webform 6, this function already exists.
In the *Result submission* page of each webform, there is a *Customize* button that allows to customize the submissions table, and un-select the fields you don't want to export.

Comment: Thanks, i will try webform 6. Didnt notice that.